# Running a Function in the background while asking for more inputs

Tags: function, selenium, multiprocessing

I am creating a little data processing script using selenium. Where I input my values and it runs a function to do the task on a website. I would like to queue inputs so that I can enter the new values while it works on the old ones.

```
    while customername != 1:
            print("Customer name")
            customername = input()
            print("Credit amount")
            creditamount = input()
            addcredit(driver, customername, creditamount)
```

How would I get the function addcredit() to run while the loop continues and asks me for the next set of inputs?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit more research, I used Threading.

```
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=addcredit, args=(driver, customername, creditamount))
    p1.start()
```

this is allowing my script to run as intended.. where it starts the action and then allows me to type more data in to run the action again. from my understanding when the function called in the second thread sleeps it bounces back to the first thread and continues on. someone, please correct me if I am wrong.